# How can I have a float[] from an IList<float> with xamarin android?

Tags: c#, floating-point, xamarin.android

I want to have a float[] from an `IList<float>`. For example, if I have

```
    var floats = new[] { 1.0f, 2.0f, 3.5f };
```

values is an `IList<float>` and I want to write:

```
floats=(float[]) values;
```

I have an exception saying that this cast is not authorized. How can I fix that problem?

Comment: Maybe [`IList.CopyTo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist(v=vs.110).aspx) is helpful.

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear, but to create an array from an IList can be done with: `list.ToArray()`

Comment: Is it really `IList` or `List`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, unless the underlying type of `values` ***is*** `float[]` then this cast will fail.

From the evidence presented, I'm assuming you have some other concrete type, perhaps `List<float>` stored in `values`.

Even though both implement interface `IList<float>`, `List<float>` is a different implementation and does not inherit from `float[]`. The cast fails.

Thinking about things in a more natural way: Say you have `IAnimal` interface, and `Human` and `FruitFly` implementations. It doesn't make sense to say `IAnimal human = new Human()`, then to say `FruitFly b = (FruitFly)human`. This is what you are currently trying to do.

So, you need to *convert* your `IList<float>` to an array. You can do this by including `System.Linq`:

```
using System.Linq; //at top of file
```

and using the [`Enumerable.ToArray`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736(v=vs.100).aspx) extension method:

```
floats = values.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you're looking for:

```
var floats = new[] { 1f, 2f, 3f };
var list = floats.ToList();
var newFloatsArray = list.ToArray<float>();
```